For nested menu's attach the inner menu it's own button
Good day everyone,
I needed some nested menu in my app so I created. You may see the reproduction. Also see the code below:
  <v-app>
    <v-container class="d-flex justify-end">
      <v-menu location="left" :close-on-content-click="false">
        <template #activator="{props}">
          <v-btn icon v-bind="props">
            <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card class="px-0 pa-2">
          <v-list max-height="300px">
            <v-list-item v-for="item, index in 20" :key="index">
              <v-menu location="left" :attach="`#btn-${index}`">
                <template #activator="{props}">
                  <v-btn
                    v-bind="props"
                    @click="logButtonRef"
                    ref="buttonRef"
                    :id="`btn-${index}`"
                    >activator</v-btn
                  >
                </template>
                <v-card color="green"> Inner Card </v-card>
              </v-menu>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
        </v-card>
      </v-menu>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted, nextTick } from 'vue'
  const buttonRef = ref([])

  onMounted(async () => {
    await nextTick()
    console.log('on mounted', buttonRef.value)
  })

  const logButtonRef = () => {
    console.log('buttonRef', buttonRef.value)
  }
</script>

After creating the nested menus, I attached the innermost menu to its own button for the scrollable state and made it stay where it was first created when scrolled, but this caused a problem like this:

I can no longer place the inner menu to the left of its own button. I tried v-menu's offset attribute, but I couldn't get it to work. Also, when I wrote custom style, it didn't produce any results.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions you may have.
Tried set v-menu's location attribute to left and doesn't work.
Tried set v-menu's offset attribute to a number array(like [-20, -20] etc.)
Tried give some static margin and transform: translateX()
